# VIM php omnicomplete - multi level object hierarchy

Tags: php, vim, omnicomplete

I'm working on existing php project with complex object hierarchy. Netbeans is a big help here, because of its autocomplete feature (it's not perfect, but in many cases is accurate enough). It's nearly impossible to remember all those attributes, relations etc.

But, netbeans is written in java, it's slow, bloated, etc.
Recently, I've been playing with vim and thinking about ditching netbeans.
I'm currently using this script: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3171

One thing I'm missing is autocomplete for multiple levels of objects, e.g.:

a.php

```
<?php
class A {

  /**
  * @var B
  **/
  public $b;

}
```

b.php

```
<?php
class B {

  /**
  * @var C
  **/
  public $c;

}
```

c.php

```
<?php
class C {

  /**
  * @var D
  **/
  public $d;

}
```

test.php

```
$a = new A();
$a-> //omni complete here works fine, it lists "b"
$a->b-> //displays 'b' again, instead of 'c'
```

So, it only works for first level.. is it possible somehow to get this functionality in vim?

If not, how do you find your way in such projects?

Answer (score 2):

Your public properties are nothing but empty variables:

```
public $b;
```

Because you didn't give it any property/method or made it an instance of `B()`, you shouldn't expect Vim to propose any useful completion for `$b->`.

With:

**a.php,**

```
<?php
class A {
  public $b = new B();   
}
```

**b.php,**

```
<?php
class B {
  public $c = new C();
}
```

**c.php**

```
<?php
class C {
  public $c;
}
```

and **test.php**

```
<?php
  $a = new A();
  $a-> // proposes b
  $a->b-> //proposes b

  $b = $a-> // proposes b
  $b = $a->b;
  $c = $b-> // proposes c
  $c = $b->c;
  $d = $c-> // proposes d
```

So… the PHP completion plugin is probably a bit limited (no surprise, Vim is a text editor, not an IDE) but it appears to work if you stick to a more conventional (and readable) coding style.

Again, Vim is *only* a text editor. A very powerful one, but it is still *only* a text editor. There are situations where a bloated IDE **is the right tool for the job**, however slow it is, however you like Vim.

Comment: That won't work in php - you can't instantiate objects directly in class properties. I've used phpdoc type hinting, because that works in most php IDE's and I'm not sure if ctags can be configured to parse that correctly.

Comment: Yes. My code is not correct PHP at all. Terribly bad. But that was on purpose, actually: because Vim doesn't understand anything about your code and `ctags` doesn't support PHPdoc hinting I don't know of a way to use PHPdoc hinting for completion in Vim. The only way to get what you want seems to be to write awful illegal code.